# Why is $\frac{\frac{a}{b} - \frac{b}{a}}{\frac{a+b}{ab}}$ = a - b?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm given the complex rational expression

$$\frac{\frac{a}{b} - \frac{b}{a}}{\frac{a+b}{ab}}$$

and asked to simplify. The solution provided is $a - b$; however I get $\frac{a^2 - b^2}{a+b}$.

My working:

Numerator first:

$$\frac{a}{b} - \frac{b}{a}$$

Least common denominator is $ab$.

Multiplying each part to get the LCD in the denominator on both sides I get:

$$\frac{a}{b} \cdot \frac{a}{a} - \frac{b}{a} \cdot \frac{b}{b}$$

$$= \frac{a^2 - b^2}{ab}$$

Multiplying this expression by the reciprocal in the original problem:

$$\frac{a^2 - b^2}{ab} \cdot \frac{ab}{a+b}$$

$$= \frac{ab(a^2-b^2)}{ab(a+b)}$$

Cancel out common factor $ab$:

$$\frac{a^2 - b^2}{a + b}$$

Where did I go wrong and how can I arrive at $a - b$?

Comment: Soooo close.  Factor the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that $$\frac{a}{b}-\frac{b}{a}=\frac{(a-b)(a+b)}{ab}$$ so we get
$$\frac{(a-b)(a+b)ab}{(a+b)ab}=a-b$$

Answer (score 2):

$$a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$$ If $a+b\ne 0$, you can divide both the numerator and denominator by it.

Answer (score 0):

You did nothing wrong. Factor the numerator $a^{2} - b^{2}$ into the difference the squares:

$$a^{2} - b^{2} = (a + b)(a - b)$$

This will leave with:

$$\frac{(a+b)(a-b)}{a+b}$$

Finally, cancel the $a+b$ expression from the numerator and denominator to obtain the desired result.